# How can I exchange the middle two 64 bits in a 256 bit AVX(YMM) register

Tags: x86, simd, avx

Is there any way to exchange the middle two 64 bits in a 256 bit AVX(YMM) register?

I know we can leverage VPERM2F128 to swap the low 128 and high 128 bits, and vshufps seems could only work inside both high and low 128 bits.

So I am wondering is there any efficient instructions to work for this typical situation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're gonna need to use both the shuffle and the permute. There's no instruction that both has 64-bit granularity and can cross the 128-bit boundary. I think AVX2 will be able to do it in one instruction though.

Comment: I suspect there's some sort of architectural barrier separating the two halves of a YMM register. The AVX reference specifically states that, for VPERMILPS/VPERMILPD, which should otherwise be able to do this job with no problem, "source elements are restricted to lie in the same source 128-bit region as the destination".

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all! I found AVX2 vpermq may well work for this.